# Website as background on linux

Tags: linux, gnome, website, desktop-customization, fedora-17

Is there some way to set a website as a background? I would like it to behave just like a wallpaper (links should not be "clickable"), but it should refresh every x minutes automatically.

My DE is GNOME3 (on Fedora 17), but I am more than happy to convert if this feature is provided by other DE. I am not interested at anything other than Linux.